# How To Save and Retrieve path image in SQLite android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i want to save and retrieve image path in my application

this is my DBhelper

```
public void insert(String kdstore,String nama, String alamat, String kodepos, String notel, 
        String lng, String lat ,String Perus,String gambar){

    //waktu = new Date().toString();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("kdstore", kdstore);
    cv.put("nama", nama);
    cv.put("alamat", alamat);
    cv.put("kodepos", kodepos);
    cv.put("notel", notel);
    cv.put("lng", lng);
    cv.put("lat", lat);
    cv.put("Perus", Perus);
    cv.put("gambar", df.fileName);
    System.out.println();
    getWritableDatabase().insert("alfamapp", "name", cv);
}
```

and this is my startCameraActivity

```
_path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/DCIM/Camera/";
        fileName =  String.format(System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg");
        File file = new File(_path, fileName);
        try {
        file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

        startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

how can i save path from cameraActivity in my database??
please help me :)

---

i put code to inserting on startCamera method,,this code like this

```
public void startCamera() 
{
    Cursor c = helper.getById(almagId);
    c.moveToFirst();

    file = new File(_path, fileName);
    try {
    file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }    

    file1 = new File(_path, fileName);
    try {
    file1.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
    finishActivity(IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    Uri outputFileUri1 = Uri.fromFile(file1);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri1);
    startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    System.out.println(file1);

    Dbhelper helper = new Dbhelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("update alfamapp set gambar ='"+file+"',gambar1 ='"+file1+"' " +
                "where kdstore='"+helper.getKdStore(c)+"'");
    db.execSQL("insert into image (kdstore,image1) values ('"+helper.getKdStore(c)+"','"+file+"')");
    db.execSQL("update image set image2 ='"+file1+"' where kdstore='"+helper.getKdStore(c)+"'");
    db.close();
    helper.close();
    load();

    System.out.println(db);

}
```

and then this code to retrieve  this image

```
if(helper.getGamb(c).equals("")){
        System.out.println("gamb kosong");
        detGam.setImageResource(R.drawable.gambarnf);

    }else detGam.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(helper.getGamb(c)));
```

you have solution to my code??thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onActivityResult` for saving path after capturing photo.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if( requestCode == IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase sql = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        sql.execSQL("insert statement for inserting path to database");
        sql.close();
        dbHelper.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Dbhelper class and camera class two defferent class

Comment: Dbhelper and cameraActivity is different class,,where can i put this method??thax

Comment: That is not a problem. please put above code in `startCameraActivity`, we are using an instance of DBHelper in this activity.

Comment: i have method insert in camera class like this 'helper.insert(kdstore.getText().toString(),nama.getText().toString(),alamat.getText().toString(),
      kdpos.getText().toString(),notel.getText().toString(),lng.getText().toString(),
      lat.getText().toString(),Perus.getText().toString(),fileName);' what should i do with this method??

Comment: Is your insert method can insert path into your DB? if so which parameter is for image path? I guess filename parameter is the image path. am I right?

Comment: i try your code and it work,,thnak you :).now how i can retrieve this image back from database??i try to image back but my application allways force close..thank you :)

Comment: If this answer helps you then please accept it as answer so that it can be helpful for others as well and it will improve your accept ratio so that people take interest to answering your question. Are you saving image in database or image path only? Please post your code that causes force close.

Comment: how i can save more image with other name??i try to do this but saved in same name..thank you

Comment: Every insert operation results adding of new row to DB. Can you please post the code that inserting and retrieving data

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for getting the image path...

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case SELECT_IMAGE:
            String imagePath = getPath(data.getData());
            Savingimagepath(imagePath);
            img.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(imagePath));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the sample method for saving the path in database

```
private void Savingimagepath(String imagePath) {
    testDatabase testDB = new testDatabase(contact.this);
    testDB.open();

    try {
        testDB.getexecute("delete from ctoffice");
        testDB.getexecute("insert into ctoffice (idnt1)Values('"
                + imagePath + "')");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    testDB.close();
}
```