# Android Application Database to Save Images

Tags: android

I am very beginner in this developing android application. I developed one application already which captures image and detect face from it than save it in gallery of my mobile. Now i want to store this captured image in my own created database. So please guide me .

1) how to create my own database.
2) how to save captured image into this database.
3) Please let me know the procedure step by step.

The code that detect the face and all that stuff is here in this link.

http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-programming-tutorials/face-detection-example-tutorials-in-android/

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code

[Android SQLite Database with Multiple Tables](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-sqlite-database-with-multiple-tables/)

and only save the image path to database
Create a table to save images.
For that there will be a auto increment column and another column

[How To Save and Retrieve path image in SQLite android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155105/how-to-save-and-retrieve-path-image-in-sqlite-android)

Comment: Ameer i read the code and trying to understand it. It is regarding how to create a database for tables and how to link them. Then all the details. But can you please let me know where exactly you want me to put this image path?