# Cannot upload image with size more than 2mb+

Tags: java, android, image, upload

I want to show a large image in my Crud Layout. I success upload image with size 1mb+ but can't upload image more than 2mb.
any solution? maybe reduce an Image file size before uploading to SQLite server?
here's my code

I will really appreciate if you help me

CRUDActivity

```
package foodsqlitedemo.quocnguyen.com.foodsqlitedemo;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class CrudActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText edtName, edtPrice;
    Button btnChoose, btnAdd, btnList;
    ImageView imageView;

    final int REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY = 999;

    public static SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_crud);

        init();

        sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(this, "FoodDB.sqlite", null, 1);

        sqLiteHelper.queryData("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FOOD(Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name VARCHAR, price VARCHAR, image BLOB)");

        btnChoose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                        CrudActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY
                );
            }
        });

        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try{
                    sqLiteHelper.insertData(
                            edtName.getText().toString().trim(),
                            edtPrice.getText().toString().trim(),
                            imageViewToByte(imageView)
                    );
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Added successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    edtName.setText("");
                    edtPrice.setText("");
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        btnList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(CrudActivity.this, GudangList.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    public static byte[] imageViewToByte(ImageView image) {
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        return byteArray;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY){
            if(grantResults.length >0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
              Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY);
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You don't have permission to access file location!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
        }

        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
            Uri uri = data.getData();

            try {
                InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    private void init(){
        edtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtName);
        edtPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPrice);
        btnChoose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChoose);
        btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        btnList = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnList);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    }


}
```

Gudang.java

```
package foodsqlitedemo.quocnguyen.com.foodsqlitedemo;

/**
 * Created by Quoc Nguyen on 13-Dec-16.
 */

public class Gudang {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String price;
    private byte[] image;

    public Gudang(String name, String price, byte[] image, int id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.image = image;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public byte[] getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(byte[] image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

GudangList.java

```
package foodsqlitedemo.quocnguyen.com.foodsqlitedemo;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Quoc Nguyen on 13-Dec-16.
 */

public class GudangList extends AppCompatActivity {

    GridView gridView;
    ArrayList<Gudang> list;
    GudangListAdapter adapter = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gudang_list_activity);

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new GudangListAdapter(this, R.layout.gudang_items, list);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // get all data from sqlite
        Cursor cursor = CrudActivity.sqLiteHelper.getData("SELECT * FROM FOOD");
        list.clear();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int id = cursor.getInt(0);
            String name = cursor.getString(1);
            String price = cursor.getString(2);
            byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(3);

            list.add(new Gudang(name, price, image, id));
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {

                CharSequence[] items = {"Update", "Delete"};
                AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(GudangList.this);

                dialog.setTitle("Choose an action");
                dialog.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                        if (item == 0) {
                            // update
                            Cursor c = CrudActivity.sqLiteHelper.getData("SELECT id FROM FOOD");
                            ArrayList<Integer> arrID = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                            while (c.moveToNext()){
                                arrID.add(c.getInt(0));
                            }
                            // show dialog update at here
                            showDialogUpdate(GudangList.this, arrID.get(position));

                        } else {
                            // delete
                            Cursor c = CrudActivity.sqLiteHelper.getData("SELECT id FROM FOOD");
                            ArrayList<Integer> arrID = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                            while (c.moveToNext()){
                                arrID.add(c.getInt(0));
                            }
                            showDialogDelete(arrID.get(position));
                        }
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    ImageView imageViewFood;
    private void showDialogUpdate(Activity activity, final int position){

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.update_gudang_activity);
        dialog.setTitle("Update");

        imageViewFood = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageViewFood);
        final EditText edtName = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.edtName);
        final EditText edtPrice = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.edtPrice);
        Button btnUpdate = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);

        // set width for dialog
        int width = (int) (activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels * 0.95);
        // set height for dialog
        int height = (int) (activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels * 0.7);
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
        dialog.show();

        imageViewFood.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // request photo library
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                        GudangList.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        888
                );
            }
        });

        btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    CrudActivity.sqLiteHelper.updateData(
                            edtName.getText().toString().trim(),
                            edtPrice.getText().toString().trim(),
                            CrudActivity.imageViewToByte(imageViewFood),
                            position
                    );
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Update successfully!!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                catch (Exception error) {
                    Log.e("Update error", error.getMessage());
                }
                updateFoodList();
            }
        });
    }

    private void showDialogDelete(final int idFood){
        final AlertDialog.Builder dialogDelete = new AlertDialog.Builder(GudangList.this);

        dialogDelete.setTitle("Warning!!");
        dialogDelete.setMessage("Are you sure you want to this delete?");
        dialogDelete.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                try {
                    CrudActivity.sqLiteHelper.deleteData(idFood);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Delete successfully!!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
                }
                updateFoodList();
            }
        });

        dialogDelete.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialogDelete.show();
    }

    private void updateFoodList(){
        // get all data from sqlite
        Cursor cursor = CrudActivity.sqLiteHelper.getData("SELECT * FROM FOOD");
        list.clear();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int id = cursor.getInt(0);
            String name = cursor.getString(1);
            String price = cursor.getString(2);
            byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(3);

            list.add(new Gudang(name, price, image, id));
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        if(requestCode == 888){
            if(grantResults.length >0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 888);
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You don't have permission to access file location!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
        }
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if(requestCode == 888 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            try {
                InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                imageViewFood.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

GudangListAdapter.java

```
package foodsqlitedemo.quocnguyen.com.foodsqlitedemo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Quoc Nguyen on 13-Dec-16.
 */

public class GudangListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private  int layout;
    private ArrayList<Gudang> foodsList;

    public GudangListAdapter(Context context, int layout, ArrayList<Gudang> foodsList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.layout = layout;
        this.foodsList = foodsList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return foodsList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return foodsList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    private class ViewHolder{
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView txtName, txtPrice;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        View row = view;
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

        if(row == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(layout, null);

            holder.txtName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            holder.txtPrice = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtPrice);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgFood);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        Gudang gudang = foodsList.get(position);

        holder.txtName.setText(gudang.getName());
        holder.txtPrice.setText(gudang.getPrice());

        byte[] foodImage = gudang.getImage();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(foodImage, 0, foodImage.length);
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        return row;
    }
}
```

SQLiteHelper

```
package foodsqlitedemo.quocnguyen.com.foodsqlitedemo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement;

/**
 * Created by Quoc Nguyen on 13-Dec-16.
 */

public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public SQLiteHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    public void queryData(String sql){
        SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
        database.execSQL(sql);
    }

    public void insertData(String name, String price, byte[] image){
        SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
        String sql = "INSERT INTO FOOD VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?)";

        SQLiteStatement statement = database.compileStatement(sql);
        statement.clearBindings();

        statement.bindString(1, name);
        statement.bindString(2, price);
        statement.bindBlob(3, image);

        statement.executeInsert();
    }

    public void updateData(String name, String price, byte[] image, int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();

        String sql = "UPDATE FOOD SET name = ?, price = ?, image = ? WHERE id = ?";
        SQLiteStatement statement = database.compileStatement(sql);

        statement.bindString(1, name);
        statement.bindString(2, price);
        statement.bindBlob(3, image);
        statement.bindDouble(4, (double)id);

        statement.execute();
        database.close();
    }

    public  void deleteData(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();

        String sql = "DELETE FROM FOOD WHERE id = ?";
        SQLiteStatement statement = database.compileStatement(sql);
        statement.clearBindings();
        statement.bindDouble(1, (double)id);

        statement.execute();
        database.close();
    }

    public Cursor getData(String sql){
        SQLiteDatabase database = getReadableDatabase();
        return database.rawQuery(sql, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }
}
enter code here
```

Comment: Instead of storing image as a BLOB to database you should store as a image path or image name. Also if the image size is _>=2b_ you can compress the image before sending it to server

Comment: how to store as a image path or image name? idk how to do it. I already search it on other thread but i still dont understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It is not advisable to store large BLOBS or similar data in the SQLite database. You should use the file system and only store a reference to the data in you database**

1. Generally you should avoid blobs in SQLite as they perform poorly; instead save the blob data as a file and store the location of the file in your DB.
2. There's a limit of 1MB on internal assets due to dynamic decompression; the 1MB limit also seems to apply to Cursor blobs but this doesn't seem to be documented anywhere.

**so you store your image in internal directory and its path is insert in SQLite DB so its easy for you**

Comment: can you give me example  how to store image in internal directory and its path?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155105/how-to-save-and-retrieve-path-image-in-sqlite-android